# how to switch the internet connection in linux with multiple internet connections

Tags: linux, networking

I am using arch linux,

I have multiple internet connections:

one is wifi and other 3G usb modem

First my wifi started and then 3G internet started. The networkmanager shows both are UP. But wifi internet is being used. Now in between i want to use 3G modem for some purpose.

```
    Question1: How to switch to 3G internet using some command line command.
```

the following are the connections information from the network manager.

```
  3G connection

  IP address: 10.178.202.42
  Broadcast Address: 10.179.255.255
  Subnet Mask: 255.252.0.0
  Primary DNS: 8.8.8.8


  WIFI Connection:

  IP address: 192.168.4.160
  Broadcast Address: 192.168.7.255
  Subnet Mask: 255.255.248.0
  Primary DNS: 192.168.0.1
```

I know that wifi is being used because i read that the first connection will be default. `Question2: But how to check which is default using some command,`

Also the output of the command:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 wwan0
10.176.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.252.0.0     U     7      0        0 wwan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

`Question3: I cant understand what this output means. What is the difference beyween gateway and DNS`

Also ip output:

```
      $ ip a
      1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 00:1d:ba:07:87:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 00:21:5d:e8:77:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.4.160/21 brd 192.168.7.255 scope global wlan0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 fe80::221:5dff:fee8:773a/64 scope link 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      4: wwan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 02:15:75:3d:29:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 10.178.202.42/14 brd 10.179.255.255 scope global wwan0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 fe80::15:75ff:fe3d:2927/64 scope link 
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I the above output what is the inet: it shows a "/"  eg in wwan0: 10.178.202.42/14. `Question4: what does that 42/14 means.`

Comment: 42 is the last octet of the ip address. /14 indicates that the subnet mask is 14 bits long (255.252.0.0). that means that in the network 10. there are 64 subnets each containing 262142 hosts, and the network you are in runs from 10.176.0.0 -- 10.179.255.254.

Comment: in case it hasn't been covered, a gateway is the local address of a router that traffic to the lan in question must be sent to. The Default gateway is the route to 0.0.0.0, the unknown network. routes are choosen by selecting the most specific route to a destination. if no specific route can be found, the traffic will always be sent to the default gateway (the route to the destination 0.0.0.0)

Comment: DNS and gateways have nothing to do with eachother. DNS is what you use when you want to send a packet to www.google.com, but don;t know the IP address. you ask the dns server what the IP for a given name is. once you have the IP, you can create a packet and send it. the route table then determines what route to use to send it, and may select the default gateway if it is the most specific route known.

Answer (score 0):

```
route del default gw 192.168.4.160  
route add default gw 10.178.202.42
```

Comment: also how to know which is presently the default.

Comment: `ip route get 1.0.0.0`

Comment: Gateways are usually routers that connect that connect to another network. A dns server will resolve a name like wwww.google.com and point it to 1.2.3.4 so say you type in www.google.com your computer will send a dns request to dns server and it will return with the ip your computer should connect to. to obtain web page. ps. to those who think my comment is noob. I would post a more technical comment however I'm trying to make this as simple as I can for Santhosh Yedidi. If you can improve my answer go for it. :)

Comment: Unless using policy routing, there can only be one default gateway. If you don't want to delete it, you can instead add two new routes to 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 using your desired gateway. Because these are more specific, they will be preferred.

Comment: i checked the above command it give "SIOCDELRT: No such process"

Comment: can you tell me what is the gateway address of wlan0 and wwan0. Tim williams you were using 192.168.4.160 which is the IP address of my computer.Is IP considered as Gateway address.

Comment: that command I write above will delete your default gateway ip(192.168.4.160) and set 10.178.202.42 as default gateway. A work around with the error SIOCDELRT is to set gateway in /etc/network/interfaces like so iface eth0 inet static address 192.168.0.20 netmask 255.255.255.0 network 192.168.0.0 broadcast 10.179.255.255 gateway 10.178.202.42

Comment: As-is, its like you're sticking in minimal place holders, and asking others to make your answer better; I've noticed you do this a couple times now.  If you don't have the time/ability to formulate a full answer, please consider using comments instead.

Comment: Hey @techie007 it was a once off. The answer I posted will fix the problem. I would like someone to improve this answer as I want the person asking to get the best answer. What is wrong with that?

Comment: sometimes I wonder why I even bother help out on this superuser.

Comment: The time you spent commenting on your answer could have been used to make the answer more full, and clearer in the first place.  Anyhow, do what you will, and realize others can do the same.  Your help is appreciated, but sometimes you might garner a downvote, and lose some imaginary Internet points, all part of the deal. :)

Comment: @techie007 some users well where the f*ck is your answer?

Comment: @TimWilliams Calm down dude. I'm just trying to help keep the site quality up, and letting you know how you can help do the same. Not bagging on you just because you're you.

Comment: `route` is deprecated, use `ip route` instead.

Comment: for the first time i have to use instead "route del default gw 0.0.0.0" it worked without error. then i could use `route add default gw 10.178.202.42`